# In file '.\docker-compose.yml', service 'ï»¿version' must be a mapping not a string

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-compose, yaml

The same question has been asked on SO and they all have the answer that it's an indention issue or encoding.

I tried parsing my YML at http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and it parses fine.

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    image: testdocker/api
    container_name: testdocker_api
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Production
```

Not sure why getting this error when doing docker-compose up

> Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

Comment: Do you have some odd characters in the file?

Comment: @DavidG, Typed all of it and no copy paste. To ensure all is well , did not use numlock and num pad. I could not see any odd/ special charecters

Comment: Which text editor did you use for this?

Comment: Probably unrelated but you have a typo twice in the word enviroNment of which the first one will also break your compose file.

Comment: @DavidG, Visual Studio 2017.Did also try creating the file in Notepad++ and copied to target dir.

Comment: @Peter, Fixed typo. But yes, It's unrelated, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably be help to all .NET developers who are creating docker-compose file in Visual Studio 2017.

> Creating docker-compose file in Visual Studio 2017 was the issue.

Steps taken to solve :

> 1. I used Notepadd++ and this time created a YAML file as template.
> 2. Create you YML configuration.
> 3. Copy to your project directory.
> 4. Run `docker-compose` up

This helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: Very strange that visual studio 2017 still has this issue, with a simple text  file !!